# get separate values instead of getting values inside a loop

Tags: php, for-loop

i am using a for loop and it returns 3 ids . but how to get those three ids separate instead of getting it inside a for loop. my code is

```
        <? $meta = get_post_custom_keys();
            $prev = '';
            foreach ($meta as $key) {
                $parts = explode (':', $key);
                if (count ($parts) == 1 || $parts[0] != 'download')
                    continue;
                $value = get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), $key, true);
                echo "<a href='$value'>{$parts[1]}</a>";

            }
        ?>
```

now in the above echo `"<a href='$value'>{$parts[1]}</a>";` gets 3 diffrent values of $values everytime it runs but how to get those ids separate such as value 1 , value 2 and value 3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store the $value in an array as `$value[] = get_post_meta (get_the_ID(), $key, true);`

Comment: how to use values outside the loop as value1, value2,value3

Comment: considering you are storing the values as an array, `foreach ($value as $v) echo $v;`